# Floating div 100% not affecting outer div

Tags: css, html, height, floating

I started tossing some HTML and CSS around and decided on making a layout that had a main div holding the header, and a content and sidebar div, both floating. Both of these have margins and borders of 2% all around.

Everything but the footer and header have a height of 100%, however, the floating divs protude from the bottom of the main div.

This is the CSS code of the main div and the two floating divs:

```
.main {
clear: both;
background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
width: 85%;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
height: 100%;
}
.content {
float: left;
width: 66%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
margin: 2% 0 2% 2%;
}

.sidebar-right {
width: 20%;
float: right;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
```

im not sure if i should insert the full code here (first post), so i used a jsFiddle

As shown in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jess_Nielsen/ePM76/
Fullscreen version: http://jsfiddle.net/Jess_Nielsen/ePM76/embedded/result/

Im pretty sure i have missed some little thing, but having gone through the suggestions from the ask form twice, i hope one of you might have a soolution.

NB: The text's pixels is going to be replaced with em's later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks like this is due to everything being `height: 100%`.

Your `html`, `body`, `.main`, `.content` and `.sidebar-right` are all set to `height: 100%` which explains the behavior of the layout.  `height` is relative to parent element's explicit height, so ALL of these elements are equal to 100% the height of `html`.

This is why `.main` doesn't fully contain all of its descendant `div` elements - `.main` has the same explicit height as `.content` or `.sidebar-right`, but `.main` is expected to hold `header`, `.content` and `footer` vertically (e.g. 100% + about 200px extra).  That's why it's overflowing.  You also have margins and padding defined for the 100% height elements which gives them even more vertical height, but the parent container stays the same size because it is also explicitly set to `height: 100%`.

The cascade always flows down the DOM, never up it.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things going on here.

Your header is within your body and it is pushing your other columns down.

You also have the following on your .side-bar elements:

```
padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
margin: 2% 0 2% 2%;
```

Which is also causing them to display outside of it's container.

Removing those two things ensures that your sidebar elements are contained.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/ePM76/4/)

You could also try using heights that are less than 100%:

[JSFiddle(2)](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/ePM76/7/)